# MySql console is non-responsive

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, console, delimiter

After inputting the triggers, the console seems in an odd state where normal commands are not responded to.  Am I inadvertently doing that with the delimiter?

```
mysql> use nntp;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_nntp      |
+---------------------+
| articles            |
| newsgroups          |
| newsgroups_articles |
+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show triggers;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> USE `nntp`$$
Database changed
mysql> CREATE
    -> TRIGGER `nntp.newsgroups.before_insert`
    -> BEFORE INSERT ON `nntp`.`newsgroups`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    -> set new.hash = md5(new.newsgroup);
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> USE `nntp`$$
Database changed
mysql> CREATE
    -> TRIGGER `nntp.newsgroups.before_update`
    -> BEFORE UPDATE ON `nntp`.`newsgroups`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    -> set new.hash = md5(new.newsgroup);
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.19 sec)

mysql> show triggers;
    -> ^CCtrl-C -- exit!
Aborted
thufir@dur:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the delimiter back when you're done creating a trigger or routine, otherwise you'll have to use the same delimiter (in this case `$$`) for all statements subsequently.

For example:

```
mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> USE `nntp`$$
Database changed
mysql> CREATE
    -> TRIGGER `nntp.newsgroups.before_update`
    -> BEFORE UPDATE ON `nntp`.`newsgroups`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    -> set new.hash = md5(new.newsgroup);
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.19 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql> show triggers;
```

Note the second use of the `DELIMITER` keyword.